# Permission for User and Connection String

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, connection-string

I use C# Asp.net and SQl 2008 R2

I'm pretty new to DB so I need some guide line.

I create a User A with Role/Permission Administrator to create my DB using MS Management Studio.

Now I need to set-up my website to READ/UPDATE/DELETE Rows in my Tables, this user will be pointed in the Connection String.

My questions:
in the connection String shall I user A (Role Admin)?
or should I crete a new User and giving role Data Reader and Data write?

I need my code able work with the content of my table but do not modifying the schema.

Please let me know. Many Thanks

Comment: hope guys is not too trivial and get down-vote, it is the first time I work with DB :)

Comment: Security is not a trivial matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new user that has the minimum permissions possible.

This way, if anyone takes over the website, they are limited to doing only what this user can do and can't do the other things the admin user can.

If you use the admin user, there is a risk that a malicious user will be able to change the schema (or even drop the database) using [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) or other techniques to inject their code into your server.

Additionally, if you have any code that would change the schema, which might be called (perhaps as an oversight or coding error), the damage is limited to what the low privileged user can do.

This is part of [defense in depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_%28computing%29).

Comment: Thanks Oded for your prompt reply. So for my understanding I should add in connection string only a User with Role Data Writer and Data Reader correct? Would make sense delete also the Admin User if I do not need in the near future? Thanks for your time on this

Comment: @GibboK - Correct, only use the user with the minimum permissions (the read/write/delete one). You could _disable_ the Admin user if you don't have any use for it.

Comment: perfect :) have a nice week-end

Comment: @Oded, great advice put simply.

Comment: What is the minimum permission that needs to be assigned to account so that my program can connect to the sql db and read a table?